# How do I get unique outputs?

Tags: powershell, unique

I would like to have unique entries in the output files.

```
$addedRecords = 0
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $rightsFileContent.Length; $i++) {
    Export-Csv $outRightsFile -InputObject $rightsFileContent[$i] -Append -Force -Delimiter ";"
    $addedRecords = $addedRecords + 1
}
```

I thought of `Select-Object` and `-Unique`, but how can I use it here?

Comment: Please show us some of the `$rightsFileContent` and also the `$outRightsFile` csv you are appending to, so we have an idea what we are dealing with. If there is sensitive information in there remember to sanitize that first.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `for` loop.

```
$rightsFileContent |
    Select-Object -Property '*' -Unique |
    Export-Csv $outRightsFile -Delimiter ';' -NoType -Append -Force
$addedRecords = $rightsFileContent.Length
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Indeed just had to let out the loop :-)
You saved my day! :)